# Register widget area above posts in WordPress Genesis child theme

Tags: wordpress, widget, genesis

I have a Genesis child theme that I'm working on ([here's my test site](http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/)) and I can't seem to figure out how to register a widget area above the posts. I see a lot of tutorials ([like this one](http://wpsites.net/web-design/add-widget-area-before-content/)) that show how to add one that spans both columns (posts & sidebar), but I'd like to have one that is only above the posts, not the sidebar.

Looking at [these hooks](http://wpsites.net/genesis-hooks/), it would be in the genesis_before_loop hook I believe. I tried tweaking the code in the tutorial I linked to but it didn't work out. Does anyone have the code or link to a better tutorial?

This is code I'm trying to use but it's not working:

```html
/**
* Add widget above posts.
*/

//* Add widget above posts 
add_action( 'genesis_loop’, ‘above_posts’ );
function above_posts() {
 
    if (is_active_sidebar( ‘aboveposts’ )) {
        genesis_widget_area( ‘aboveposts’, array(
            'before' => '<div class=“aboveposts widget-area"><div class="wrap"',
            'after' => '</div></div>'
            ) );
    }
}

//* Register widget above posts areas
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'    => ‘aboveposts’,
    'name'    => __( ‘Above Posts’ ),
    'description'  => __( 'This is the above posts widget.’ ),
) );
```

Comment: Use to StudioPress forums and/or the FaceBook Genesis group. Also, you're using curly quotes in your code. There should only be straight tick marks. Use a code editor, you will see your errors if you use a real code editor.

Comment: @Julie Do you want the widget to be before all of the posts or each post?